# Composition of Dual Maps in (rigid) Monoidal Categories

Tags: category-theory, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, monoidal-categories, model-categories

If $X, Y$ are objects in monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$ which have left duals $X^∗, Y^∗$ and $f : X → Y $ is a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$, then the left dual map $f^∗ : Y^∗ → X^∗$ of $f$ is given by:

$f^* = (ev_Y ⊗id_{X^*})((id_{Y^*} ⊗ f )⊗id_{X^*})(id_{Y^*} ⊗coev_X)$

where  $ev_X: X^∗⊗X → 1$, $coev_X : 1 → X ⊗X^∗$, and $ev_Y: Y^∗⊗Y → 1$, $coev_Y : 1 → Y ⊗Y^∗$, are the evaluation and coevaluation corresponding to $X,Y$ respectively. I am trying to show that if objects in $X,Y,Z \in \mathcal{C}$ which have left duals $X^*,Y^*,Z^*$, and $f : X → Y, g : Y → Z$ are morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$, then $(gf)^*=f^*g^*$. Is the definition of of $f^*$ is equivalent to the following:

A left dual map of $f$ is the morphism $f^∗ : Y^∗ → X^∗$ which is uniquely determined by the commutative diagram
[image]

Comment: You should always be able to translate string diagram manipulations into equations. If you can't, perhaps you should start by reviewing that.

Comment: What I did is I used the fact that $Y$ can be viewed as a right dual of $Y^*$ and took the composition for string diagrams. But I still feel there is something wrong with my computation when translating into equations; Actually the composition does not even make sense.

Comment: I suggest you review the definition of a dual object in a monoidal category. You can use the axioms to solve both questions, first that $f^*$ satisfies the diagram you state and second that the composition of duals is the dual of the composition (reversing the order).